# Recommending Course Certifications

Tags: discussion, moderators

I voted this [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12790/what-are-the-best-ai-courses-leading-to-ai-certifications)n as off topic. Now, ignoring the fact whether it is off topic or not one of the answer by @AlenParker provides link to some courses, all of which are offered in a profit based manner (profit for the offering company). And out of those links at-least 2 are probably trustworthy (MIT and probably ARTIBA).

My problem is should we allow such answers to exist which promote some links which are clearly profit based and also cannot be trusted? This is especially highlighted with the example of a very popular company named Udemy which hosts courses for profit (but no verification) is made whether the instructor is qualified or not? Atleast 2 famous YouTubers (who provide free programming courses) have spoken out against the quality and copyright violation of these courses. So, should we allow such links to be posted? Organisations like EdX, Coursera and Udacity are fine since they are transparent, non-profit (generally according to them money goes in improving the course) and in general takes a nominal fee to provide courses from famous instructors and colleges which kind of verifies the course content.

So what are your thoughts on these? Keep in mind more important than than the spam viewpoint of these answers is that if someone genuinely tries these super pricey courses and does not get money's worth, the person is likely to squarely put blame on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that this type of questions should be closed as off-topic and, anyway, they will lead to primarily opinion-based answers. However, we have already a lot of these questions on the website.

I think that the quality of the answers should be assessed using the voting system. If someone does not agree with the suggestions, then he/she should downvote the answer (and possibly leave a comment in order to encourage the answerer to improve his/her answer). Furthemore, it is the reponsibility of the asker to accept or not an answer. In general, the web is full of misleading and incorrect information, so it is the responsibility of the web surfer to select or not any information.